# Make a QEMU+KVM guest export USB mass storage to host?

Tags: usb, qemu, linux-kvm

So I'm really wondering if you can use a QEMU+KVM guest as a USB device. I'm really just playing around and have no very clear use-case for it. But one imaginable thing is to setup the guest so that its storage is automatically synchronized to some server and then it can export files from that storage as encrypted mass storage devices to the host.

But really, I'm just curious. :)